# Why does a grouplayout resizes a parent gridbaglayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm using a gridbaglayout in my parent panel to set the sizes in weight proportionate to the window size.
then I add panel inside it and set its layout to grouplayout.it overrides the weights I have set in its parent and takes more space than it is supposed to.If I change the values in grouplayout it gets fixed,but I'm wondering why it override the parent panel assigned sizes?

here is my code and images:

```
    GridBagLayout gbl_panelMain = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_panelMain.columnWeights = new double[]{0.05,0.9,0.05};
    gbl_panelMain.rowWeights = new double[]{0.24,0.72,0.04};
    panelMain.setLayout(gbl_panelMain);
    panelContent = new JPanel();
    panelContent.setOpaque(false);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_panel_2 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_panel_2.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gbc_panel_2.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_panel_2.gridx = 1;
    gbc_panel_2.gridy = 1;
    panelMain.add(panelContent, gbc_panel_2);
```

before I add GroupLayout :

[image]

```
   GroupLayout gl_panelContent = new GroupLayout(panelContent);
    gl_panelContent.setHorizontalGroup(
        gl_panelContent.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 253, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    gl_panelContent.setVerticalGroup(
        gl_panelContent.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 358, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    panelContent.setLayout(gl_panelContent);
```

after :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Grouplayout does not respect its parent size restrictions.When I replaced the fixed sizes in the following lines with the GroupLayout.Preferred_Size the problem was solved.

```
.addGap(0, 253, Short.MAX_VALUE)
.addGap(0, 358, Short.MAX_VALUE)
```